# On Windows, what's the difference between the various Scripts folders?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

On a Windows installation of Python, what is the difference among the following?

- `"PythonInstallFolder"\Scripts\`
- `%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts\`
- `%APPDATA%\Python\Python36\Scripts\`

Also, should all be on my path?

I have multiple versions of python installed.

- Python27 -> `C:\Users\nahawk\Python\Python27\`
- Python36 -> `C:\Users\nahawk\Python\Python36\`

Output

```
C:\>where pip
C:\Users\nahawk\Python\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\nahawk\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe

C:\>where pip2
C:\Users\nahawk\Python\Python27\Scripts\pip2.exe

C:\>where pip3
C:\Users\nahawk\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip3.exe

C:\>where cookiecutter
C:\Users\nahawk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\cookiecutter.exe

C:\>where futurize
C:\Users\nahawk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\futurize.exe
C:\Users\nahawk\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts\futurize.exe
```

Comment: Normally scripts will be installed in "Scripts" for the installation or virtual environment. `%APPDATA%\Python` is used by --user installations. It's actually a bad idea in general to install applications in `%APPDATA%`. Someone didn't have his or her thinking cap on. This is the user's roaming profile. That's horrible for network congestion if users are downloading a profile that has something like the SciPy and matplotlib packages in it. It should have used `%LocalAppData%\Python`.

Comment: As to the change to `%APPDATA%\Python\Python36\Scripts` for 3.6, this stems from the disdain for using versioned script and executable names on Windows. Putting everything for all versions in one "Scripts" directory was thus an unworkable mess. Now it uses a versioned directory instead. This puts the burden of `PATH` management on the user. So I suggest completely avoiding --user installs and minimizing what you install to the main Python installation to instead use virtual environments. Create shell links that run `cmd /k path\to\activate.bat` to easily start an environment.